# How to set custom text on buttons in JFace Wizard (Java)

Tags: java, button, jface, wizard

I am using JFace Wizard and I want to set my own text on buttons Next, Back, Finish and Cancel. I found only very old advices which are completely useless today. I also found some solution with external jar files, but I really don't want to add whole library to project only for setting text on 4 buttons...

Is there any reasonable solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After massive finding and trying, I have to say there is no such way. There are some brutal solutions, but compared with them, adding one jar file to project is much easier and nicer.

I will cite best working solution for me:

> You need to download a language pack from here:
>
> http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/L-3.2.1_Language_Packs-200609210945/index.php
>
> NLpack2-eclipse-SDK-3.2.1-gtk.zip works for me while I'm using Eclipse
>   3.7.2.
>
> Extract org.eclipse.jface.nl2_3.2.1.v200609270227.jar (or other nl for
>   your language) from the archive and add it to your project. It will be
>   used automatically.

This do not let you to set texts on buttons, but at least gives you texts translated into your language.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614399/how-can-i-change-buttonss-text-in-org-eclipse-jface-wizard-wizard). Seems to be the answer to your question.
It basically says to create a dialog using WizardDialog class. Create a class that inherits from Wizard with the implementation of your choice then do below:

```
WizardDialog wizardDialog = new CustomWizardDialog(shell, new YourWizard());
```

and then in your CustomWizardDialog do the following:

```
public class CustomWizardDialog  {
    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);

        Button finishButton = getButton(IDialogConstants.FINISH_ID);
        finishButton.setText("FinishButtonText");

        Button cancelButton = getButton(IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID);
        cancelButton.setText("CancelButtonText");
    }
}
```

All that is left is to perform wizardDialog.open() to open dialog.